# Wordpress Password Encryption

Tags: wordpress, hash, admin, md5

I am not familiar with Wordpress so sorry if this is a stupid question.

For some reason, when a user logs in to admin (or is registered), her/his password is sent to the database in plain text.

I have read that one should not use MD5 with WP, but use wp_hash_password, as found in wp-includes/pluggable.php

Having looked through the site files, it seems to be using this. However, passwords are definitely being sent in plain text (therefore I assume also stored in plain text).

How can I change the settings to have the passwords sent encrypted?

Comment: They're being *sent* in plain text? Or they're being *saved* to the database in pain text? What's the concern?

Comment: @mevius definitely being send in plain text. I know this because one of our security experts 'sniffed' the network and found it. From a security aspect, this means that a determined hacker could also see the username & password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to prevent passwords being "sniffed" is to use the https protocol - the way WordPress stores a password is irrelevant in this case.

You'll need an SSL certificate (cloudflare.com are giving them away) and this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/

Comment: FWIW, you don't need a plugin. But as mentioned, you do need an SSL Cert.

Comment: @mevius I won't be using plugins as I don't like the way they add so much superfluous code and server calls. Normally i wouldn't use Wordpress, but.....